# What is the right way to count article comments, hits, and likes in an articles index?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, performance

I have three tables, one for articles, one for comments, one for likes, one for visits, in this example schema

```
**news**
  news_id

**comments**
  comment_id
  news_id

**likes**
  like_id
  news_id

**hits**
  hit_id
  news_id
```

What i want to do is to listen all the articles in a sortable index in a box/div for each article with article count of hits, comments, and likes, i know how to do all this, so it's not the how i am seeking, it's the best way, i am thinking about those two solutions.

1. do it the normal way, a complex SQL query then cache the query let's say for an hour or two.
2. write a script that is executed every two or three hours to calculate the data and store it in the same news table in "news_hits, news_likes, news_comments" numeral fields.

and of course the third way is to do the query each time the page is loaded without any caching.

i feel that it's method number one that i shall go after, but i wanted a professional or experienced opinion, i am not expecting a huge number of visitors, around 500-1000 a day maximum, but still i want to be prepared for high traffic.

thank you,

Rami

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be best to admit redundancy in this case, to improve speed. To the news table, add these fields:

```
comments_count int not null default 0,
likes_count int not null default 0,
hits_count int not null default 0
```

When a comment/like/hit is added/deleted, if the database supports triggers, trigger an increment/decrement of the referenced counter, and if not - do it manually on each insert/delete (stored procedure maybe?).

This type of data is more often read than written, so to optimize read speed, slowing down write speed and storage space isn't a big deal.

From time to time, it would be OK to run a query that would update these counters if by some reason they become erroneous.

Comment: yep that cuts it for me, it's the type of answers that makes you say, why haven't i thought about that? :D .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Break the complex SQL into several smaller queries (less complex) and cache the individual result(s), so in anytime you want to prepare warm-up cache, it won't take too many database resources

Comment: +1, for the tip, but i prefer a non-caching solution before enabling cache, just to make sure i'm doing it the best way possible, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

With such a simple model, query and low number of visitors I would go for the straight query. It will execute just fine (milliseconds) with proper indexing.

If I understand the scenario correctly, the query should sort news articles by their popularity, which is determined in some way by the nr of likes/hits/comments.

If you are set on fixing a performance problem you may not actually run into, the simplest "solution" would be to use a query cache that expires every 10 seconds. With your current load, each visitor would basically always render the view from the database since the cache expires between page visits. If, one day you suddenly become overrun with say 200,000 visitors, you would only perform the query once every 10 seconds.